# Plot an ODE solution for a list of specific constants

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Let's say I have a 1st order ODE and want to plot the solution. What I have been doing until now is:

```
eq = y'[x] + 1/x y[x] == 4 x^2
y[x]/x + Derivative[1][y][x] == 4 x^2

solution = DSolve[eq, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> x^3 + C[1]/x}}
> ```

```
yy = solution[[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> x^3 + C[1]/x
> ```

```
partialsolutions = Table[yy /. C[1] -> i, {i, -3, 3}]
```

> ```
> {-(3/x) + x^3, -(2/x) + x^3, -(1/x) + x^3, x^3, 1/x + x^3, 2/x + x^3, 3/x + x^3}
> ```

```
Plot[Evaluate[partialsolutions], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

With the above code I plot the solution for all values of `C[1]` from `-3` to `3`, but if I only wanted to plot the solution for `C[1] = -1`, `2` and `3` how should I change the code? I found the above method in a book, but it is for a range of values of `C[1]`, not specific values, which is what I want to do.

Comment: You could just use specific values in the table
`partialsolutions = Table[yy /. C[1] -> i, {i, {1,5,9}}]`

which gives the solution for 1, 5 and 9

Comment: `partialsolutions = Map[yy /. C[1] -> # &, {-1, 2, 3}]` Open up the docs and read about `Map`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific example in the OP, the following simple approach works:

```
ps = yy /. C[1] -> {-1, 2, 3}
```

> [image]

```
Plot[ps, {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

In general, in addition to the suggestions in the comments above, you can also use

```
ps = Thread[yy /. C[1] -> {-1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: ... replacing `C[1]` by the list `{-1, 2 3}` works because both `Divide` and `Plus` are `Listable`.